# multiline environment variable in /etc/environment

Tags: environment-variables

Title says it all really. I'm trying to set an RSA private key in /etc/environment. Things I've tried include wrapping the variable in single and double quotes, add a backslash at the end of each line and adding '\n' at the end of each line.

Comment: Answered on [so]. See [shell - How to Export a Multi-line Environment Variable in Bash/Terminal e.g: RSA Private Key - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457787/how-to-export-a-multi-line-environment-variable-in-bash-terminal-e-g-rsa-privat)

Comment: May I ask what is the point of putting private keys in /etc/environment? That's loaded into the environment of most processes – it is much less safe than just storing them in a normal file...

Answer (score 4):

From [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49489260/15087622):

**export the key**

```
export PRIVATE_KEY=`cat ./gitbu.2018-03-23.private-key.pem`
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$PRIVATE_KEY";
```

If you want to save the key to a `.env` file with the rest of your environment variables, all you needed to do is "wrap" the private key string in *single quotes* in the `.env` file ... e.g: `sh exports HELLO_WORLD='-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEA04up8hoqzS1+APIB0RhjXyObwHQnOzhAk5Bd7mhkSbPkyhP1 ... iWlX9HNavcydATJc1f0DpzF0u4zY8PY24RVoW8vk+bJANPp1o2IAkeajCaF3w9nf q/SyqAWVmvwYuIhDiHDaV2A== -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'` 
So the following command will work:

```
echo "export PRIVATE_KEY='`cat ./gitbu.2018-03-23.private-key.pem`'" >> .env
```

Followed by:

```
source .env
```

Now the key will be in your .env file and whenever you source .env it will be exported.